# NavigateUrl in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET. I am having problem with NavigateUrl.

```
<td align="right" valign="middle">
    <p id="posCstmr">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkContact" CssClass="addbtn-cmplist" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "Actions/Contact.aspx?ContactID=" + Eval("ContactID") + "&CompanyID=" + Eval("CompanyID") %>' Text="View"></asp:HyperLink>
    </p>
</td>
```

When I click to view following hlnkContact, it redirects to the following link with specified values which is OK.

[http://localhost:1426/Actions/Contact.aspx?ContactID=78724&CompanyID=92971]

But I want to store these values in session variables on Page_load event of Contact.aspx.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
     Session["ContactID"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ContactID"].ToString()) ? String.Empty : Session["ContactID"];
}
```

But I cant store the Session variable on Page_Load because NavigateUrl show the values after loading of this page.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Same type of question was answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21200064/690329), you can tweak like below:

**[Assuming that the td is inside any databound container, else `Eval` wouldn't work]**

Change your markup to this:

```
<td align="right" valign="middle">
    <p id="posCstmr">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"  CssClass="addbtn-cmplist" runat="server"
            Text="View" CommandName="Link" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ContactID") + ";" + Eval("CompanyID") %>'
            OnClick="ButtonLink_Click" />
    </p>
</td>
```

Code:

```
protected void ButtonLink_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
    string[] arguments = lb.CommandArgument.Split(';');
    string ContactID = arguments[0];
    string CompanyID = arguments[1];

    //Save in session
    Session["ContactID"] = ContactID ;
    Session["CompanyID"] = CompanyID ;

    //Redirect
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("Actions/Contact.aspx?ContactID={0}&CompanyID={1}", ContactID, CompanyID));
}
```

Comment: Thanks afzalulh, It is storing values into Session variables but I ran into other problem. Contact forms shown Blank or empty. Its without any control even not lable controls showing a white page. Any idea? [http://localhost:1426/Actions/Contact.aspx?ContactID=78724&CompanyID=92971]

Comment: What you have in contact's Page_Load? Try to type `localhost:1426/Actions/contacts.aspx?ContactID=78724&CompanyID=92971` in the browser and see if the page loads.